# How to add JList object to a BorderLayout type Panel?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, jlist

I'm having trouble trying to add a JList to the WEST side of my panel.

I was able to successfully add a text field and search button on the NORTH by using another panel and adding it to the original panel.

```
JPanel panelShop = new JPanel();

    // Example of items in the scrollbar list
    String[] results = { "Result 1", "Result 2", "Result 3", "Result 4"};
    JList searchList = new JList(results);
    searchList.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    // Sets the number of items to display without requiring to scroll
    //searchList.setVisibleRowCount(4);
    panelShop.add(searchList, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

The problem is the last line of code, when I'm trying to add the JList to the WEST border of the original panel.

Nothing shows up.

Thanks!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I shorten it...that better?

Comment: It's not self compilable.

Comment: how should I go about allowing you to compile my code without posting long codes on here?

Comment: Take all the excess crap out of it.  I could add a list to a component, put it in a panel, and get it on-screen in under 20 LOC.

Comment: wow good for you!....and cant even address anything related to my issue

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class TextJpanel extends JFrame {

public TextJpanel() {
    JPanel panelShop = new JPanel();
    panelShop.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    // Example of items in the scrollbar list
    String[] results = { "Result 1", "Result 2", "Result 3", "Result 4" };
    JList searchList = new JList(results);
    searchList.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    // Sets the number of items to display without requiring to scroll
    // searchList.setVisibleRowCount(4);
    panelShop.add(searchList, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(panelShop);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TextJpanel test = new TextJpanel();
    test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    test.setSize(200, 200);
    test.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

make sure if you want to use the gridlayout for a JPanel then u have to set a GridLayout manager to this panel.